# Install Mint and Ubuntu on separate drives: how many grub installers needed?

Tags: linux, boot, grub2

I would like to setup a dual boot system using **Mint** and **Ubuntu**, with each on a drive of its own.  Would I install each as a distinct OS with its own **grub** installer, or will they have to be on just one installer?
I will be installing each from a live CD.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want **Mint** on */dev/sda*, and **Ubuntu** on */dev/sdb*.

Only one OS needs the **grub** installer, preferably **Mint** on the boot disk.  After you install **Ubuntu**, rerun `sudo update-grub` on **Mint**, and **grub** will detect and make menu entries for both OSes.

But even if you installed **Mint**, then **Ubuntu**, and used the **grub** installer on both, it should still work OK.

Comment: Ok Thanks.  I thought it would be ok, just was not sure.  I,m new to linux, had a number of issues getting started, so I am being very cautious in proceding further without knowing just what I am doing is correct.